# Show $D(x, y)=\max \left\{d_{1}(x, y), d_{2}(x, y)\right\}$ is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be metrics on M. Show that $D$ given by $D(x, y)=\max \left\{d_{1}(x, y), d_{2}(x, y)\right\}$ is also a metric.

I can't figure out how to show the triangle inequality. So far I have:

$$
D(x,z) = \max \{d_1(x,z),d_2(x,z)\}
\leq \max \{d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z),d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)\}
$$

This is were I'm stuck!

Comment: Distinguish cases; it's a commonly needed thing for arguments involving min or max.

Comment: thanks @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 2):

Just distinguish the cases: if $\max \{d_1(x,z),d_2(x,z)\}=d_1(x,y)$ then
$$\max \{d_1(x,z),d_2(x,z)\}=d_1(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z) \leq \max \{d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z),d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)\}$$

If $\max \{d_1(x,z),d_2(x,z)\}=d_2(x,y)$ then
$$\max \{d_1(x,z),d_2(x,z)\}=d_2(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z) \leq \max \{d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z),d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\max\{d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z), d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)\}=d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z)$. Then you certainly have that $$d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z)\leq\max\{d_1(x,y),d_2(x,y)\}+\max\{d_1(y,z),d_2(x,z)\}=D(x,y)+D(y,z)$$ If $\max\{d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z), d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)\}=d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)$, the argument is the same.